# python requests: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxies'

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using python 3.7 on cygwin. the version of Requests is 3.22.

```
Tim.Zwart@VIXION /c/c/U/t/D/e/cloud_server# python3.7 excelposttest.py 
/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "excelposttest.py", line 35, in <module>
    req = requests.Request("POST", 'https://exceltocodeazure20190222112103.azurewebsites.net/api/Function1', data=data, headers=headers, proxies=proxiesspec)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxies'
```

the relevant code is this:

```
req = requests.Request("POST", 'https://exceltocodeazure20190222112103.azurewebsites.net/api/Function1', data=data, headers=headers, proxies=proxiesspec)
```

Comment: How about `requests.post('https://exceltocodeazure20190222112103…)`, less confusion?

Comment: Also I like to add that I'm very impressed that you typed the answer in less than a second.

Comment: I was about to post this as a genuine question when a colleague showed me the error of my ways, so I checked the 'answer your own question' box and wrote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `requests.request` method has almost the same name as  `requests.Request`, a class within the same module. So misspelling by capitalizing the first letter does not lead to a `function undefined` kind of error but instead to this.